# How do I cope with a co-worker when he constantly leaves the toilet door open

Tags: human-resources

My co-worker always leaves the toilet door open when he takes a pee.  I have told him on numerous occasions that this is not appropriate.  He just laughs and has ignored my requests to shut the door when he uses the bathroom.

Comment: Just to clarify the situation - Am I correct in assuming this a 'unisex' bathroom where everyone uses the same space, and not a mens-only bathroom (where open urinals would be normal)?

Comment: @brhans Either way leaving the door open is unconscionable;

Comment: @PeterM - how so? In mens-only bathrooms, the urinals are not mounted in stalls with doors - so there is no door to close. A man standing and urinating in a toilet stall with the door open in a mens-only bathroom is equivalent to performing the same action at a urinal (and probably actually less 'exposed' since he's enclosed at the sides by the toilet stall walls which don't exist at the urinals).

Comment: Need a location tag, as some cultures don't make as big a stink out of this as others. Also, if you're a woman (I'm guessing because of your username) this may open certain legal paths to be explored (such as sexual harassment if he continues).

Comment: @brhans You need to step back into the corridor.  If someone out in the corridor can see someone else inside a toilet peeing, it doesn't matter what type of the facility the pee-er is peeing in.  Also note the OP's name and her complaint of her co-worker being a `He`

Comment: @PeterM - ok, we're talking about different things here. I'm talking about what would normally be visible to someone who is already inside a mens-only bathroom (with multiple toilet stalls and/or urinals). You seem to be talking about what could be visible to someone completely outside a bathroom with a single toilet. I'm asking the OP to explicitly clarify the situation so that we don't have to guess at genders or spaces.

Comment: @brhans IMHO there is already enough description built into the OPs question to establish that she is seeing undesired pee-ing at her place of work.  In fact gender doesn't really even come into it.

Comment: @PeterM you're completely missing the point. It's up to the OP to clarify that the situation is in fact of a woman who is seeing a man urinating in a shared/unisex toilet. Reading between the lines and guessing may not be helpful in the long run. We don't know that "Helen Watkins" is a woman any more than we know that "Peter M" is a man or what gender "brhans" is. We don't know if this is a single toilet directly accessible from an office corridor or if it's one of many toilet stalls in a larger bathroom which itself might be shared between genders. *Good answers require good questions!*

Comment: @brhans There is no need to read between the lines.  The question is explicit.  At work place "W" Person "A" believes that the Behavior "B" of Person "B" is inappropriate, and has relayed this directly to Person "B" on multiple occasions.  Person "B"'s response to laugh off Person "A"'s request and keep performing Behavior "B".  Person "A" asked the question of how to cope with this.  You don't need any more details than that.

Comment: @PeterM OK, you don't need information.  It is OK for others to want more information.

Comment: Yeah, I'm gonna need more info because even though OP might be offended or think it is inappropriate, without more info nobody can give a definitive answer without the clarification of whether or not it is actually offensive or inappropriate.

Answer (score 12):

Escalate it to HR/management. He's a grown man, not a child, and basic consideration needs to be given to others.

Comment: Isn't that overstepping a little bit?  You want someone to get fired over bathroom habits?

Comment: Is it really? How happy would you be if you were walking down a hallway at work and can see somebody having a piss? You tell him that it isn't appropriate, and he laughs at you and keeps on doing it? Do you seriously think it's appropriate in the workplace? If the guy gets fired over it, more than likely this isn't the first time something like this has been brought to the attention of HR/management and is just part of a history of unacceptable behaviour.

Comment: Well, that escalated quickly.  Aren't you assuming many things that the OP never indicated?

Comment: @DonThermidor_LobsterMobster If he were to get fired, it is by his own design.

Answer (score -1):

Go together with a group of friends.  Laugh.

Repeat until he learns.

Comment: As much as this would work, it could be seen as a form of harassment.

Comment: @user1666620 I didn't say laugh at him.  It's a good way to announce one's presense.

Comment: If he´s the rough joking kind, I´d get my phone and take pictures of him until he feels the need for more privacy and learns to use the door...